# how to generate .htaccess rewrite rule for the following condition

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi I need the following URL

***www.example.com/index.php?page=continent&con=europe***

into the following format

***www.example.com/europe***

when I use the following method this working but conflict with another rule

> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=continent&con=$1

but this conflict with :

> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1

I need both ways

please help

Comment: RewriteRule ^(europe|america|asia|australia|africa)$ index.php?page=continent&con=$1

Comment: you need to avoid same pattern otherwise it will conflict

Comment: Make sure you put the rule from HerrSerker before the other

Comment: Still I couldn't use both 
RewriteRule ^(europe|america|asia|australia|africa)$ index.php?page=continent&con=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Thank you so much its working fine 
btw may I know how to link images and css to this condition